# create a soundbar with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, soundcloud

I looked into different solutions, such as this one that I improved with a button : http://jsfiddle.net/3mhJJ/.

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  $(".bar").each(function(i) {fluctuate($(this));});
});
```

I would like to be able to pause the recording, and also to stop the animation when the sound is over ( I didn't include it, but just imagine the sound lasts 10 seconds)

I have never worked with jQuery, but I am familiar with AngularJS, do you think there is any way for me to do this only with JQuery or by mixing JQuery and AngularJS together?

Otherwise, I'd like to recreate something like Soundcloud but I am not sure how hard it is.

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure that I understood what you're after but here's how to start/stop the animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/kyysdo4n/2/ (updated to include an auto-stop feature)

```
var stopAnimation = false;
var closeTimeoutHandle = null;

function fluctuate(bar) {
    if(stopAnimation){
      return;
    }

    var amplitude = Math.random() * 10;
    console.log(amplitude);
    var height = amplitude * 4;
    //Animate the equalizer bar repeatedly
    bar.animate({
        height: height
    }, function() {
        fluctuate($(this));
    });
}

$("#btnStart").click(function(i) {
    stopAnimation = false;
    fluctuate($('.bar'));

    closeTimeoutHandle = setTimeout(function(){
        stopAnimation = true;
    }, 10 * 1000); //10 seconds
});


$("#btnStop").click(function(i) {
    stopAnimation = true;
    fluctuate($('.bar'));
    // clear the timeout so that if the user starts the animation again
    // it doesn't get stopped when the initial timeout gets called
    if(closeTimeoutHandle){
        clearTimeout(closeTimeoutHandle);
    }
});
```

I'm not sure if this helps .. if it doesn't then please add more details, maybe more code ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) This was exactly what I was looking for. However, is it possible to stop the animation after a certain amount of time if the user forgets to click on stop?

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: I updated it on order to have only one button, which changes of color depending if you are listening or not to music. 
http://jsfiddle.net/kyysdo4n/4/
Could be useful to add a play or pause button for example :)